# Synchronizing Changes From File Geodatabase to SDE Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, replication

I have an SDE geodatabase that has a one way replication to a file geodatabase, where I will make edits to the feature classes offline somewhere. I know that this scenario doesn't support one-way or two-way replication, so is there anyway I can push the updates I made in the file geodatabase back to the SDE geodatabase?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, its' not convenient, but you could just use a check-out replica. By not convenient, i mean that its a one-shot deal: you have to recreate the child and check back in every time you want to create edits. How often do you need to do this? How much data are we talking about?

It would be fairly easy to automate this process via model builder or arcpy.

Oh, I forgot to ask: do you have ArcGIS Server? If so, you could then easily set up a GeoData Service: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_geodata_service/015400000329000000/